# In networkx 2.1, if a graph is assigned to a new empty graph and edges are removed from new graph why it is removing edge from old graph?

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I have created a graph by merging 4 graphs by

```
WaterWayNWK=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(WaterWayUID,'Node-A','Node-B',['Distance'])
RoadNWK=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(Road_ODUID,'Node-A','Node-B',['Distance'])
RailNWK=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(RailUID,'Node-A','Node-B',['Distance'])
TerminalNWK=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(TerminalUID,'Node-A','Node-B',['Distance'])
Network_lst=[WaterWayNWK,RoadNWK,RailNWK,TerminalNWK]
SynchoromodalNWK=nx.compose_all(Network_lst)
```

then I am assigning this to an empty dummy graph

```
    Dummy=nx.Graph()
    Dummy=SynchoromodalNWK
```

finally, I am removing nodes from the new graph and calculating the number of edges in both.

```
print('before removal:',len(SynchoromodalNWK.edges()))
Dummy.remove_nodes_from(['RI3_1177', 'WI3_1177'])
print(len(Dummy.edges()))
print(len(SynchoromodalNWK.edges()))
```

output is coming as :-

```
runfile('C:/Users/NaVnEeT/Desktop/adj/untitled2.py', 
wdir='C:/Users/NaVnEeT/Desktop/adj')
before removal: 2343
2339
2339
```

Why are the edges removed from original?

Answer (score 0):

In Python [variable names are *bound* to values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

`Dummy=nx.Graph()` binds the variable name `Dummy` to the value `nx.Graph()`.

The assignment `Dummy=SynchoromodalNWK` rebinds `Dummy` to the value `SynchoromodalNWK`,
rendering the first assignment nugatory.

So after this assignment, `Dummy is SynchoromodalNWK` is True. Both variables, `Dummy` and `SynchoromodalNWK` are "bound to" (or you could say "refer to") the same value.
Modifying `Dummy` modifies `SynchoromodalNWK`.

If you want `Dummy` to be a [copy](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.copy.html) of `SynchoromodalNWK` (so that modifying `Dummy` will not affect `SynchoromodalNWK`), use

```
Dummy = SynchoromodalNWK.copy()
```

`Dummy=nx.Graph()` is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you, now it is working the way I want it to. Also, It is an important lesson for me about python variable assignment.